# Does Android Application Upgrade call the Class that extends Application?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi is the Class that extends Application Called when doing an Update  from Playstore.
My problem is that I have initialized  SQLiteDatabase on onCreate function of my Application Class. When I do and Upgrade my App Crashes with the below error

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.isOpen()**

Which means SQLiteDatabase is not initialized on UPDATE.

Any Ideas???

Below we is more

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.isOpen()' on a null object reference
at com.cellulant.consumerapp.db.DBAdapter.getSqliteDatabase(DBAdapter.java:518)
at com.cellulant.consumerapp.fragments.PaymentsFragment.onCreateView(PaymentsFragment.java:113)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1235)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1083)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1609)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2733)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17923)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2461)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1463)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1341)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6700)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

DB Apdater

public class DBAdapter extends SQLHelper {

```
private CustomerTable customerTable;
private ProfilesTable profilesTable;


/**
 * @param context   Application Context
 * @param dbName    Database name
 * @param dbVersion database version
 */
public DBAdapter(Context context, final String dbName, final int dbVersion) {

    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    customerTable = new CustomerTable();
    billsTable = new BillsTable();

}

/***
 * Create individual table needed in database
 *
 * @param sqlDB Database
 */
private void createInitialTables(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {

    try {
        customerTable.createTable(sqlDB);
        billsTable.createTable(sqlDB);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtils.showException(e);
    }


}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    createInitialTables(sqlDB);
    super.onCreate(sqlDB);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
}

/**
 * This method is responsible for closing the database connection.
 *
 * @param db Database
 */
public void close(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.close();
    //Check if there is any open connection before closing.
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    super.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);


    if (oldVersion < 21) {


        boolean tableSMSTemplateColumnIsDefault = StringUtils.checkIfColumnExists(db, SMSTemplateTable.class.getSimpleName(), SMSTemplateMap.PARSE_TYPE);
        if (!tableSMSTemplateColumnIsDefault) {
            db.execSQL(ALTER_SMS_TEMPLATES_PARSE_TYPE);
        }
        boolean tableMerchantColumnIsDefault = StringUtils.checkIfColumnExists(db, MerchantPayersTable.class.getSimpleName(), MerchantPayersMap.IS_DEFAULT);
        if (!tableMerchantColumnIsDefault) {
            db.execSQL(ALTER_MERCHANT_PAYER_IS_DEFAULT);
        }



    }

}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getSqliteDatabase() {
    if (!super.getSQLiteDatabase().isOpen()) {
        open();
    }
    return super.getSQLiteDatabase();
}

/*
 * Getter Methods
 */

public CustomerTable getCustomerTable() {
    return customerTable;
}

public ProfilesTable getProfilesTable() {
    return profilesTable;
}
```

}

Comment: Difficult to answer without code. Please post more detailed stacktrace, and your application class

Comment: Yves Delerm Above is more Stacktrace

Comment: Thanks. I think seeing how your db is initialized in your application class and retrieved in your DBAdapter could help too

Comment: I still do see where your db is initialised, but I guess you could try to replace db initialisation in your application class by initialisation within a singleton object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Android Application Upgrade call the Class that extends Application?

Not directly. An application upgrade will terminate your process. When a new instance of your process is created, a new instance of your `Application` subclass will be created. Exactly *when* a new instance of your process will be created varies, depending on app setup, what the user is doing, etc.

Bear in mind that any of your activities might be the starting point for the user when your process is created. The user *frequently* will start at your launcher activity, but that is not always the case.

For example, suppose your launcher activity is Activity A, which opens Activity B, which opens Activity C. At this point, the user gets the `Notification` that an update is available. So, the user taps on that `Notification`, goes to the Play Store (or wherever), and requests to update the app. Your process gets terminated along the way. Once the upgrade is finished, the user returns to your app (home screen launcher icon, overview/recent-tasks list, etc.). At this point, you will get a new process... and Activity C will be created and brought to the foreground. If your code assumes that the user will always go through Activity A, you may have problems.

This is not unique to app upgrades. The user could have gone A->B->C, pressed HOME, gone into another app for 10 minutes, then returned to your app. Your process might well have been terminated while your UI was in the background, just to free up system RAM. Once again, when the user returns to your app, you will get a new process, and the user will see Activity C, not Activity A.